# Grade Average Calculator

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

Here is the question I am working on :

> You want to know your grade in Computer Science, so write a program
>   that continuously takes grades between 0 and 100 to standard input
>   until you input "stop" , at which point it should print your average
>   to standard output.

Here is my code thus far in Python 3:

```
total = 0
q = 1
score = input("Enter a score:")
while score != "stop":
    q += 1
    total = total + int(score)
avg = total / q
print(avg)
```

I am very new at coding, and could use some help to point me in the right direction. I feel its important for me to learn, so nobody should feel obligated to just hand me the correct answer.

Comment: read your inputs into a list

Comment: Shouldn't `q` start at 0?

Comment: Also, don't you need another `input` within the loop?

Answer (score 4):

I'll give you a thorough outline to help you with this process algorithmically.

- Total variable to 0, count variable to 0, and use an empty input string.
- Create a while loop that runs until the input variable is the word stop.
- Add input as integer to total. Add one to the count. Take input again.
- Outside of loop divide total as float divided by the cumulative count.

Now let's try putting this algorithm together in code. Do as I do down below.

```
# Code Block 1

count = 0  # count variable
total = 0  # total variable

enter = '' # input variable

while enter != 'stop':
    enter = input('Enter a grade:' )

    if enter != 'stop' and enter.isdigit():
        total += int(enter) # add to total value
        count = count + 1   # then to the count

print float(total) / count




# Code Block 2

numbers = []

while enter != 'stop':
    enter = input('Enter a grade:' )

    if enter != 'stop':
        numbers.append(int(enter))

print sum(numbers) / float(len(numbers))
```

Comment: Everyone's comments to my question was very helpful, thank you! Unfortunately MyProgramming Lab will not accept anything with the following:  a count, a + sign, any enter.isdigit or variations thereof.  I have learned that it looks for a very specific way of coding.

Comment: Then use a list, take a look at the new block of code.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you might be going into an infinite loop. Your while statement is waiting for score to change, but you don't modify score within the loop. You should add

`score = input("Enter a score:")`

inside of your while loop.

Answer (score 1):

The following code was accepted by my Person textbook.  The question specified the following caveat, but otherwise appears to be the same question: "When reading the input, do not display a prompt for the user. Use the input()function with no prompt string."

```
total = int()
numOfGrades = int()
grade = str()
average = float()

grade = input()

while grade != "stop":
    numOfGrades = numOfGrades + 1
    total = total + int(grade)
    average = total/numOfGrades
    grade = input()
print (average)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
total = 0
total_quiz = 0
inpt = input("Stop? or enter score")
while inpt.upper() != "STOP":
    if int(inpt) < 100 and int(inpt) > 0:
        total += int(inpt)
        total_quiz += 1
    else:
        print("Score to high or to low")
    inpt = input("Stop? or enter score")
print(total / total_quiz)
```

Since your new, you should also know correct indentations is very important in python.

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop is not indented but I don't know if this is a typo - your main problem is that you need an if statement and your input statement needs to be in the while loop, this is a very simple program that just alters your code (so you should understand it):

```python
total = 0
q = 0 #need 0 so counter is correct
score = "" #need to declare score

print("Enter 'stop' to exit program") #Need to tell user how to quit
while score != "stop": # you can use while score.lower() != stop to check all cases
    score = input("Enter a score:") 
    #You need to ask the question everytime so it should be in the while loop
    if score == "stop": #This is the part you were missing a conditional statement
        break           #if statment in this case that exits the loop when score is stop
    total += int(score) #you can use += here too
    q += 1 #moved from top so it doesn't add on the last run (when exited)

avg = total / q
print(avg)
```

Using a similar if statement to check if (hint search for else if) the variable is between 0 and 100 I leave to you but feel free to ask if you're still stuck.

Answer (score 0):

That's the answer in my lab programming:

```
total = 0
count = 0
grade = input("")

while grade != "stop":
    total += int(grade)
    count += 1
    grade=input("")

        
average = total / count
print(average)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).