# Average grades using a while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

I am trying to average grades using a while loop. Here is the program requirements:

*Let the user enter grades to average. The user may type any number of grades; when he or she types “quit” or “Quit” print the average, rounded to two decimal places.*

Please keep advice relatively simple. First time programming. Only am familiar with for loops and while loops and if else statements right now.

I was given this skeleton code:

```
def main():
    '''Average grades entered by the user'''
    #Set the total to 0
    #Set the grade count to 0
    #Get a grade
    #While the grade is not "quit" or "Quit"
    #    Add the grade to total
    #    Add one to the grade count
    #    Get a grade
    #Average the grades
    #Round the average to two decimal places
    #Print the average

main()  #Start execution
```

Here is my code thus far:

```
def main():
    '''Average grades entered by the user'''
    total = 0#Set the total to 0
    grade_count = 0#Set the grade count to 0
    grade = int(input('Enter grade :'))#Get a grade
    while grade != 'quit' or grade != 'Quit':#While the grade is not "quit" or "Quit"
        total += grade#    Add the grade to total
        grade_count += 1#    Add one to the grade count
        grade = int(input('Enter grade :'))#    Get a grade
    average = total / grade_count#Average the grades
    round(average, 2)#Round the average to two decimal places
    print(average)#Print the average

main()  #Start execution
```

And this is the error I am getting:

```
Enter grade :70
Enter grade :80
Enter grade :90
Enter grade :quit
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\\trace\Class\CSC-130\004\Rall992\Asn2\Asn2-1.py", line 21, in        <module>
    main()  #Start execution
  File "\\trace\Class\CSC-130\004\Rall992\Asn2\Asn2-1.py", line 16, in main
    grade = int(input('Enter grade :'))#    Get a grade
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'quit'
```

Comment: Well, what number do you expect `quit` to be? You need to check the input before you convert it to an int.

Comment: Yes, I understand the reason for the error but do not know how to fix it.

Comment: Do not cast `grade` to an `int()` until the next lines where you add to `total`

Comment: Would you show me this? @cricket_007

Comment: You need to check for 'quit' before casting the input to an int. Change the assignment to input('Enter grade :'), then first line in while loop set grade = int(grade)

Comment: For example, `grade != 'quit'` will never be true if `grade` could be converted to a number. Just use `grade = input("Enter a grade")`, then compare `if grade.lower() != 'quit'`

Comment: More relevant duplicate.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29290556/grade-average-calculator?rq=1

Comment: You could put the `grade = int(input('Enter grade :'))` statement inside a `try/except ValueError:` and handle the exception accordingly.

Comment: Change your first line in your while loop to `total += int(grade)`. Then in your second user input, use `grade = raw_input('Enter grade :')` because otherwise Python will interpret you trying to quit the program (i.e. `exit()`)